# How to automate providing input to a prompt using bash?

Tags: bash, automation, io

I am entering a command in my bash terminal of the form:

```
gmx rdf -f 600-c6h6-MolDynamics_good-PBC.xtc -o rg.xvg -s 600-c6h6-MolDynamics.tpr -selrpos whole_mol_com -seltype whole_mol_com -b 5000 -e 10000
```

Once I enter this command, I am prompted to make a selection. I input `2`, I hit enter. I am asked to make another selection, I input `2` again, I hit enter again. Then I need to hit `command+D` to let the program do its thing.

I want to automate the process of entering these inputs (2, 2, command+d) in my bash script itself. Is this possible? How can I pull this off? I am on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: As you found out by yourself, as long as the prompting command reads from stdin, you can use input redirection.

Comment: Look into `expect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured it out. Please let me know if there is something inherently wrong about it.

```
gmx rdf -f 600-c6h6-MolDynamics_good-PBC.xtc -o rg.xvg -s 600-c6h6-MolDynamics.tpr -selrpos whole_mol_com -seltype whole_mol_com -b 5000 -e 10000 << EOF
2
2
EOF
```

This seems to do the job.